# How to sync access to file between ASP.NET web site and ASP.NET web service on one web server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, multithreading

I have deployed ASP.NET web site and ASP.NET web service on the same web server. Both of them require access to shared file.

How to implement/share lock that supports single writers and multiple readers? If somebody reads, nobody can write, but all still can read. If somebody writes, nobody can read/write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to open file for writing with allowing other threads to read it use System.IO.File.Open method with System.IO.FileShare.Read. Ie.:

```
System.IO.File.Open("path.txt",System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite,System.IO.FileShare.Read)
```

Other (reading) threads should use System.IO.FileAccess.Read

Signature of Open method:

```
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share);
```

UPDATE 
If you need all instances to ocasionally write to file. Use Mutex class to reserve file writing. Ie.:

```
    Mutex mut = new Mutex("filename as mutex name");
    mut.WaitOne();
    //open file for write, 
    //write to file
    //close file
    mut.ReleaseMutex();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ReaderWriterLock or ReaderWriterLockSlim (.NET 2.0) class from the System.Threading namespace to handle single writer / multiple reader cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
public class yourPage {
    static object writeLock = new object();
    void WriteFile(...) {
         lock(writeLock) {
              var sw = new StreamWriter(...);
              ... write to file ...
         }
}
```

Basically, this solution is only good for cases when the file will be opened for writing a short amount of time.  You may want to consider caching the file for readers, or writing the file to a temp file, then renaming it to minimize contention on it.

Comment: Wouldn't this be irrelevant if two different objects of this class are created each in its own thread? Each of them would get a copy of writeLock, thus making the entire locking scheme useless. I believe that the writeLock should be declared "upstream" before different threads are created, like in the Global.asax file.

Comment: @Tudor: If the object is "static", there is only one instance of it per process, not per thread.  The variable truly is global to all threads.  You can, however, decorate it with a [ThreadStatic] attribute, and it would be just as you describe (useless!)